# Why does constructing std::string(0) not emit a compiler warning?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, stl, compiler-warnings

Say I have this piece of code.

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Writing `std::string(0)` results in `std::basic_string<char>::basic_string(const char*)` being called, with `0` as the argument to this constructor, which tries to treat the argument as a pointer to a C-string.

Running this code obviously results in a `std::logic_error` being thrown. But my question is this : why both GCC and MSVC 8.0 don't emit any warnings? I'd expect to see something along the lines of "Making pointer from an integer without a cast".

Comment: Because `0` is a null pointer constant, and presumably no one thought that the warning would be worth the effort (really, how often does anyone write something like this?)

Comment: how would a cast help? it would be equally nonsensible

Comment: I guess I must've gotten used to that warning in my C years. Compiling `int *x = 5` with `gcc` causes "initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast" to be emitted.

Comment: Because it's very very common to initialize a pointer with a null pointer and in no way an error. Adding a warning would result in a very large number of warnings from every program.

Comment: @daniel that is not valid, but converting 0 to a pointer type is valid and produces a null pointer.

Comment: `0` is a special case here. Understood. Thanks a lot.

Comment: "Running this code obviously results in a `std::logic_error` being thrown" -- that's not guaranteed btw, your code has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`0` is an integer constant expression with value 0, so it is a null pointer constant.  Using a 0-valued constant as a null pointer is not a cast.

C++11 introduces `nullptr` (and `nullptr_t`), but the treatment of `0` as a null pointer is unlikely to change in the near future as large amounts of code depends on it.

Answer (score 1):

Because those compilers seem to miss this feature. I recommend to write them a featurereport.

A compiler can easily regognize the std string class internally and emit a sensible warning.

I don't know why you want to restrict the warning only to the cast-free cases though. Having a cast there or otherwise passing a null pointer is equally nonsensible.

Comment: I don't think the questioner really wants to restrict it to cast-free cases, it's just that he quoted the error that he's used to seeing in other cases (and which you already explained isn't relevant here anyway). The non-cast case is probably the most likely, since I expect anyone who writes `std::string(0)` is trying to call an imaginary constructor that takes a size (like `vector` has), and really means `string(0,0)`. Someone who writes `string((char*)0)` isn't making *that* mistake, they've come up with another less likely mistake of their own.