# Why isn't it a compile-time error to return a nullptr as a std::string?

Tags: c++, function, language-lawyer, stdstring

Due to a bug, I just found out that this code compiles fine on with Visual Studio 17 and probably on other compilers as well. Now I'm curious why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string foo(){
    return nullptr;
}

int main(){
    auto s = foo();
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

I could imagine it is because the `std::basic_string` c'tor could be invoked with a `char*` and while returning an implicit conversion from ptr to `std::string` occurs (with `NULL` as argument and then goes poof). Am I on the right way?

Comment: it is probably indeed passing `nullptr` as the parameter for a pointer

Comment: It compiles, but you get a runtime error.

Comment: It would probably be beneficial to add a `string (nullptr_t) = delete` ctor, just so this error is caught at compile time. I don't think legitimate programs would break due to that.

Comment: Related, [Why does constructing std::string(0) not emit a compiler warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13394212/608639), [Access Violation when sending a 0 int literal to a const string parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48210211/608639), [Avoiding improper std::string initialization with NULL const char* using g++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2407711/608639), [How to best protect from 0 passed to std::string parameters?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/220687/118658), etc.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is right, checking [`std::basic_string` constructors #5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) will be called:

```
basic_string( const CharT* s,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Note that passing `nullptr` invokes undefined behavior as stated in [the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.string#string.cons-itemdecl:6) and the notes :

> The behavior is
>   undefined if `[s, s + Traits::length(s))` is not a valid range (**for
>   example, if `s` is a null pointer**).

Comment: Interesting enough, std::string_view's constructor has __attribute__((__nonnull__)) and the compiler emits a warning when NULL or nullptr is passed to the std::string_view's constructor. I wonder, why there is no such attribute for std::string's constructor

Answer (score 13):

Why shouldn't it compile? `std::string` has the following constructor:

```
string(const CharT* s, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

that constructs the string with the contents initialized with a copy of the null-terminated character string pointed to by `s`. The constructor is **not** explicit, so the implicit conversion from `nullptr` to `std::string` is indeed possible.

Comment: Please note that passing __null__ is UB

Comment: @RichardCritten, it definitely is. But the question was why this code compiles, not what happens if the code is executed. UB will happen not only for `nullptr`, but for any pointer that doesn't point to the beginning of a null-terminated string.